# Matching pattern and extraction

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a log file which looks like below. It shows that there are many file are missing. I would like to list it.

```
$cat datafile.txt
    /data/kay/20091012.csv
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091013.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
    /data/kay/20091014.csv
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091015.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091016.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
    /data/kay/20091017.csv
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091018.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
```

I would to list the dates on which the file is missing. My script is below:

```
$script.sh
awk '{if($1 -eq "gawk")print $4}' datafile.txt
echo ${echo $(awk '{if($1 -eq "gawk")print $4}' datafile.txt):-14,8}
```

It is showing error. "Bad substitution"

My desire output:

```
$outfile.txt
20091013
20091015
20091016
20091018
```

Comment: "_It is showing error_": what error?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Your use of `echo`, command substitution and parameter expansion is totally wrong. First you don't need `echo` at all. `awk` already sends its output to the standard output by default. Echoing it is totally useless. Second you try to apply parameter expansion (more precisely the `${parameter:offset:length}` substring  expansion) to command substitution; this does not work. You can use substring  expansion only on parameters (bash variables, if you wish). Last but not least you pile up commands while `awk` or `sed` are perfectly capable of doing what you want alone. Read their manuals, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/^ +gawk/s/[^)]*_([^.]*).*/\1/woutput.txt' input_file
$ cat output.txt
20091013
20091015
20091016
20091018
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"[_.]" '/gawk/{print $3 > "output.txt" }' input_file
$ cat output.txt
20091013
20091015
20091016
20091018
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{4}[0-9]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}' input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` with your shown samples please try following solution. Using regex and lazy match concept in grep's regex.

```
grep -oP '^[[:space:]]+gawk:.*?out/[0-9]+_\K(.*?)(\.txt)'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `datafile.txt` content be

```
/data/kay/20091012.csv
gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091013.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
/data/kay/20091014.csv
gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091015.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091016.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
/data/kay/20091017.csv
gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091018.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
```

By doing

```
awk '{if($1 -eq "gawk")print $4}' datafile.txt
```

you instructed your `awk` to deduce `eq` from 1st field then concatenate it with `gawk`, as all these field are non-numbers and `eq` was not set `0`s are assumed so for each line that evaluates to

```
0gawk
```

this is considering truthy in boolean context, so it will `print` 4th field for each line (empty string if there is no such field).

You should use `==` if you need comparison and take into account that you are looking for lines where 1st field is `gawk:`, after fixing that your code becomes

```
awk '{if($1=="gawk:")print $4}' datafile.txt
```

and gives output

```
(FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091013.txt
(FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091015.txt
(FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091016.txt
(FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091018.txt
```

However `if` is not required here as GNU `AWK` uses pattern-action pairs, so above might be expressed as

```
awk '$1=="gawk:"{print $4}' datafile.txt
```

Now you need to clean output, I suggest following heuristics: keep one-or-more digits after `_` and before `.`, which might be implemented using [`gensub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) following way

```
awk '$1=="gawk:"{print gensub(/.*_([[:digit:]]+)[.].*/, "\\1", 1, $4)}' datafile.txt
```

which gives

```
20091013
20091015
20091016
20091018
```

Observe that `[.]` denotes literal dot, whilst `.` outside square brackets denotes any character.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

bare bones `ERE` `regex` suffices :

```
echo '
    /data/kay/20091012.csv
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091013.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
    /data/kay/20091014.csv
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091015.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091016.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file
    /data/kay/20091017.csv
    gawk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=/data/kay/out/501_20091018.txt FNR=1) fatal: file not file' |
```

---

```
mawk 'NF *= 2 < NF' OFS= FS='^[ \t]+gawk:[^_]+_|[.].+fatal.+$'
```

---

```
20091013
20091015
20091016
20091018
```

to further shrink the `regex` down to ***absolute*** minimum :

---

```
gawk 'NF *= 2 < NF' OFS= FS='^.+gawk:.+_|[.].+$'
```

---

and a ***REALLY REALLY*** inappropriate way of extracting that number out :

```
nawk '$+_ = +$2' FS='_' 
mawk '$0  = +$2' FS='_' 
gawk '$_  = +$2' FS='_'
```

---

```
20091013
20091015
20091016
20091018
```